# Question about proof using the chain rule

Tags: partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

The following is a proof from my textbook:

If $u(x, t)$ is a solution of $(1)$, so is the dilated function $u(\sqrt{a}x, at)$,
for any $a > 0$. Prove this by the chain rule: Let $v(x, t) = u(\sqrt{a} x, at)$. Then $v_{t} = [\partial (at)/\partial t]u_{t} = au_{t}$ and $v_{x} =[\partial(\sqrt{a} x)/\partial x]u_{x} = \sqrt{a} u_{x}$ and $v_{xx} = \sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}u_{xx} = a u_{xx}$.

I was wondering how we get that $v_{t} = [\partial (at)/\partial t]u_{t} = au_{t}$, for example? Since writing out the right-hand side of $v_{t}$ we have $\dfrac{\partial (at)}{\partial t}\cdot \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, but $\partial u$ and $\partial t$ don't "cancel out."

Comment: There's some abuse of notation going on here. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ should really be $\frac{\partial u}{\partial (at)}$.

Comment: how do we get $u_{t}$ from $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial (at)}$?

Comment: You seem to be confusing $u_t$ with $v_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write $v=u\circ g$ where $g(x,t)=(\sqrt{a} x, at)$. Then, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ can be computed by reading off from the product of the Jacobians $\mathcal J(u)\circ \mathcal J(g)=\mathcal J(v)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial t}\\ 
\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}$.